# How can I read another program's STDOUT from a Ruby program line by line?

Tags: ruby, io, stdout, stdin, popen

I have a small test Ruby program called "count", which counts 1..50.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
#count
for i in 1..50 do
 STDOUT.puts i
 sleep 1
end
```

I want to call it from another program, and read the outputted numbers line by line, and output them from the other program, line by line.

However my construction doesn't work:

```
IO.popen("count","r+") {|f| puts f.readline}
```

What should I do to make it work? Maybe some modification in the test program "count"?

Answer (score 3):

If you have some patience (about 50s worth), you'll see that you do get one line of output and that line will be `"1\n"`. You have two problems:

1. `count` is using buffered output. This means that nothing will show up in your `stdin` until `count`'s output buffer is full; given the small number of bytes that you're printing, the buffer won't be flushed until `count` finishes.
2. Your `popen` block is only looking for one line.

You can solve the first one by using [`STDOUT.sync = true`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D) to turn off the output buffering in `count`:

```
STDOUT.sync = true
for i in 1..50 do
  STDOUT.puts i
  sleep 1
end
```

Then in your `popen`, you can iterate over the lines using [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-each):

```
IO.popen("count","r+") { |fp| fp.each { |line| puts line } }
```

Then you should one line of output showing up each second.

Comment: And what if my test program is a normal program? For example cURL or WGET, How can I set the STDOUT.sync=true in this case? Or should I write a "wrapper" Ruby program which calls the normal program?

Comment: Have you tried with `curl` or `wget`? Programs that expect to be used in pipelines tend to be pipe-aware and do The Right Thing on their own. Otherwise, you wait until the buffer fills.